# Solve ODE $\dot x_{i}=\frac{1}{card(S_i)} \sum_{j\in S_i} I(x_{j},x_{i})\quad \quad (1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider continuous functions $x_j=x_j(t):[0,T] \to [-1,1]$, where $T>0$ and $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. Let also $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and consider:
$$\dot x_{i}=\frac{1}{card(S_i)} \sum_{j\in S_i} I(x_{j},x_{i})\quad \quad (1)$$
where $S_i$ is an arbitrary proper subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and
$$\label{cont_vs_lead}
I(x_{j},x_{i})=\begin{cases}
    x_{i} & \qquad  i\in \mathcal{P} \\
    r & \qquad  i\in \mathcal C \\
    \frac{x_{j}-x_{i}}{2} & \qquad i \notin \mathcal C \cup \mathcal{P}
\end{cases}$$
Here $r\in[-1,1]$, while $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal{P}$ are proper subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Is it possible to solve analytically ODE (1).

Comment: Is it true that $\dot x_i=x_i$ if $i\in\cal P$ and $\dot x_i=r$ for $i\in\cal C$? Or should the construction of $I(x_j,x_i)$ rather be based on the index $j$?

Comment: Dear @LutzLehmann, the construction of $I(x_j,x_i)$ is based on the index $j$?

Comment: At the moment your cases are decided on what the index $i$ is. As that index is constant in the sums, you get this trivialization in the first two cases with the trivial solutions $x_i(t)=x_i(0)e^t$ in the first case and $x_i(t)=x_i(0)+rt$ in the second case. This gives restrictions considering the stated domain of the problem, $x_i(0)\le e^{-T}$ in the first case, and $rT<1$, $x_i(0)\le 1-rT$ in the second case.